# Firebase: Key is undefined when added to an object

Tags: javascript, firebase

Tools React 0.14.0, Firebase 2.2.9 ( I don't think React part is important)

This question is very basic, yet is blowing my mind! Seems like a basic Javascript syntax error, but maybe Firebase is tripping me up somehow.

**I try to add a key property to an object but it somehow keeps saying it is undefined! Behold the great simplicity below!:**

```
itemsRef.on('child_added', function(snap){

           var newItem = snap.val();
           newItem["key"] = snap.key();
           console.log(snap.key());//This prints a valid key!
           console.log(newItem);//newItem.key is undefined!!
...
```

What the heck? I hope this isn't something embarrassingly simple. :)

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/daqoci/edit?js,console. It may depend on your data. For example: if your items are simple values (e.g. string or number), then you cannot add a property to them

Comment: "newItem" is a object with all it's properties are either strings or numbers. Don't know if that makes a difference @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Check the jsbin that I linked to. Your code works completely fine there. Unless you provide enough information for us to reproduce your problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll vote to close.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is right! The code is actually fine. There is a chrome dev extension that uses the "key" property on objects(I don't know much about how that all works), but it was causing me to hunt in the wrong area. I will post more about the issue later if I get the chance to understand it better.